# How can I get data from python scripts to my React web app?

Tags: python, ajax, reactjs

I currently have a simple React Web App. I want to be able to "call" a python program, which will take in input as arguments, run, and give me back the output in a JSON format for example.

What are the steps for making this type of pipeline? I've heard of terms like using ajax calls and setting up Pyton web servers, but I'm not sure of where to start.

Comment: First step would be building a REST app with python and calling api endpoints with React app.. If you don't know how to do either of those I suggest you go through their documentation or some tutorials

Comment: Have a look at TornadoWeb for creating REST API endpoints.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wU-KUapq1kQ . This is a good place to start